# John sold some books at $24 each, and used the money to buy some concert tickets...

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

John sold some books at 24 dollars each, and used the money to buy some concert tickets at $50
each. He had no money left over after buying the tickets. What is the least amount of
money he could have earned from selling the books? What is the least number of books
he could have sold?

I know the answer is $600 and 25 books. Could someone please explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you simply find the lowest common multiple of 24 and 50

reducing 24 into prime factors = $2\times 2 \times 2 \times 3$
take 50 into prime factors = $2\times 5 \times 5 $

then take the highest power of each prime factor and multiply it together which is $2^3 \times 3 \times 5^2$ = 600

Comment: Thanks a lot! The 25 books is just $600/$24 per book which was easy.